# Calculating area fraction of pixels covered by larger pixel using Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

My goal is to calculate an area fraction from one image as the threshold to select (mask)another image.

Specifically, the land cover layer has a spatial resolution of 30m and the EVI data is 250m. I want to calculate the area fraction of corn coverage (using the land cover layer) for each EVI pixel. Then the EVI pixels whose fraction values are larger than 0.7 will be extracted.

pixel-based area fraction for corn = (area of corn) / (area of each EVI pixel)

Although the GEE has the reduceRegions method, it requires to input features rather than rasters, and I did not find a method to do this task.

Could anyone help me?

Here is the data:

```
// import evi and crop data layer (CDL)
var evi = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/006/MOD13A2")
            .filterDate('2015-01-01', '2015-12-31')
            .select('EVI')    
var cdl = ee.Image("USDA/NASS/CDL/2015");

// mask other types of crop and only keep the corn
var corn = cdl.select('cropland').eq(5).updateMask(cdl.select('cropland').eq(5))
```

Comment: Welcome. From a strictly GIS perspective, I would consider upsampling the EVI raster sufficiently, perform the weighting raster calculation into an alpha/additional band, and use it to mask. I'm not sure what libraries one has access to with GEE/JS alone or if a solution exists there. You could also consider 'polygonizing' discrete rasters.